# jQuery Mobile – how to scroll list with items bound to vmouseup

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, event-handling

I have a set of list items bound to 'vmouseup' instead of 'click' because of the 300ms lag in trigger time of the event.

My problem is when I use that 'vmouseup' or 'vmousedown' to bind each list item, I obviously cannot scroll the list with some tweaks.

My list element look about this:

```
 $(liElem).bind('vmouseup', function () {
      scrollToTop();
      showDetails();
 });
```

1. How can I scroll the list without triggering the vmouseup event on list element?
2. I remember reading somewhere here in SOFlow that vmouseup isn't necessarily always triggered, so should I use vmousedown instead?

I think I know the answer to the #1 has to do with `unbind()` / `die()` with slight possibility of `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()`

**UPDATED ANSWER**

In iOS 4.2.1 (iPod Touch) seems to be something buggy with the threshold approach. Everything works fine if scrolled up (swipe from top to down) but when scrolled down (swipe from down to up) the distance, pageY, often gives false values and fires an event. For example, if threshold is set for 30 pixels and I swipe from the very bottom to the top of the phone it still could fire the event. Using jQueryMobile 1.1.0 RC1 and jQuery 1.7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var did_user_swipe = false;
$(liElem).bind('vmousedown', function () {
    did_user_swipe = false;
}).bind('vmouseup', function () {
    if (!did_user_swipe) {
        scrollToTop();
        showDetails();
    }
}).bind('vmousemove', function () {
    did_user_swipe = true;
});
```

This sets a flag that is `false` by default. The flag is set to `true` when the user drags their finger in a swiping motion. When the flag gets set to `true`, the `vmouseup` event handler will not run.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RB6mp/

## Update

You can set a threshold for swipe/click behaviors as well, which reduces the need to bind to the `vmousemove` event:

```
var coords    = [0, 0],
    threshold = 100;//in pixels
$(liElem).bind('vmousedown', function (event) {

    //when the mouse is clicked, set the coordinates of that event
    coords = [event.pageX, event.pageY];
}).bind('vmouseup', function (e) {

    //when the mouse is released, calculate the distance from the start of the click to the end
    var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(coords[0] - e.pageX, 2) + Math.pow(coords[1] - e.pageY, 2));

    //if the distance of the "swipe" is longer than the `threshold` set
    if (distance > threshold) {
        alert('Swipe (' + Math.floor(distance) + 'px)');
    } else {
        alert('Click (' + Math.floor(distance) + 'px)');
    }
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RB6mp/4/

Comment: wow.. that was quick.. thanks! knew you were lurking around the corner, jasper. And that code runs ok in iPhone and android?

Comment: I'm making a demo for you, but notice that I just updated the answer to include the `vmousedown` event to reset the flag.

Comment: Yeah, basically when the mouse button is clicked, set a flag, then when the button is un-clicked, check to see if that flag has been changed by moving the mouse/finger.

Comment: related follow up question... do i have unbind these events on each liElems before I do .innerHTML = '' on the whole list? ...because my simple app is using 30MB of memory on android and thought it might be because of possible memory leak

Comment: Use `.remove()`, is's a jQuery function that removes the selected element(s) along with any data bound to them and any event handler bound to them: http://api.jquery.com/remove/. Also, if you found the answer to be helpful an up-vote is always appreciated, and if the answer was *the* answer, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: helpful, as always your answers are, have to check the code in real device tomorrow